# Can't get navigation view to show

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I put this in my Xcode but nothing shows.

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Any reason why?

Comment: did you put it in the viewDidLoad() method?

Comment: @NickG yes Nick I did but it doesn't show up

Comment: Try to set imageView's frame to e.g. CGrectMake(0,0,40,40)

Comment: I tried to add cgrect no avail I have embedded the navigation controller but still have no show

Comment: Try setting the `contentMode` of `imageView` to `.ScaleAspectFit` and manually define the frame like Matej suggested. In my experience an image will not display if it is larger than the `titleView` unless you resize it, hence setting the `contentMode`.

Comment: @Wes ok I'm amateur so how would I do that

Comment: @SmithyT see my answer

Comment: Thanks for the help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo")!
let imageView = UIImageView(image: logo)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44)
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```